# Database table column that has multiple table foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, eloquent, schema

Lets consider three tables :

```
    1.Companies 
           id
           company_name
           ...
    2. Employees
           id
           employee_name
           ... 
    3. Payment
           id
           pay_by
           pay_to
           ...
```

Now the problem is here pay_to can be id of a Company or an Employee (fk). So I have added a Boolean column "is_company" in the Payment Table. So my solution is if is_company is True then its Company otherwise its Employee.

But I am not satisfied with this solution. I mean I don't want to have a column which has multi table foreign key. I think there has a better solution but I could not find that. Please help to find a better solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could, depending on what you using to interact with the database, prefix the pay_to with a letter, e for employee or c for company however then you can't specify that the field is an int etc which may cause issues.

One alternative is to use different ranges (this would obviously limit the number of each you could have) but you could say 0-9999999 is employees and 10000000+ is company ID's.

Another alternative would be to have an interim table (called payees for example) where pay_to references a row in that table which gives you a payee type and then the payee's ID in their respective table.
--EDIT--
You could create a table called payees with columns such as payee_id, payee_type, id. payee_id would be an auto increment column that you would then reference in the payment.pay_to field. payee_type would be company/employee and then id would either be company.id or employee.id depending on the type. It would mean using 2 queries rather than using a join but that is true with any of the possibilites unless you could combine companies and employees in to one table - this would depend on the other columns beyond what you have detailed in your original question.

None of them are necessarily elegant (and there may and probably are other) solutions, but they would be the 3 I would look at using in your situation!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am confused about interim table. It seems same what I have done already. Can you please describe it more.

Comment: @SunnoSakib - I have added an edit to explain more on what I meant - let me know if it's still unclear at all.

Answer (score 0):

to build on what Ed Wade said, you could prefix all `companies` with a `1` and all `employees` with a `2`.  This would help with keeping the field as an integer while not limiting the number you could store